# hibernate persist not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a simple `AppUser` entity class and table in db `APP_USERS`.
when i do a `addAppUser` from DAO class, I get below exception:

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to
>   persist: com.spring.model.AppUser

```
@Override
public void addAppUser(AppUser p) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.persist(p);
    logger.info("AppUser saved successfully, AppUser Details="+p);
}
```

Not sure how to resolve it. Same code works fine for persisting a different class's object. Did some research but could not find anything that could help.

Comment: AppUser was managed entity before and now it is in detached state. You can't persist detached entities, you need to merge them first to get them managed by persistence context and then only you can persist entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `AppUser` comes from the outside, so it is not managed by hibernate. Call `merge` to reattach your DAO, i.e. make hibernate handle it again:

```
session.merge(p);
```

If you still run into an exception, you can try to see if the object is already in the session first, and then call `update(obj)` if it is, otherwise call `merge(obj)`.

For example:

```
if(session.contains(obj)) session.update(obj);
else session.merge(obj);
```

Comment: Tried your solution. That helped me identify the real problem which was in entity class. I had @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) on top of String attribute. That detached the object somehow i guess

Answer (score 0):

i had issue because i had the below naive code .. didn't notice it.

```
    @Id
    @Column(name = "enterid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String enterid;
```

It was not able to autogenerate the enterid which is 'String' and it turned to null.
I noticed that during debugging.

```
Hibernate: insert into app_users (enterid, lead, enable, password, approval, role, teamname) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```